# Jquery UI autocomplete combobox disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using the Jquery-UI auto-complete plugin [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) implementation, but i changed the script so that the input element added by the plugin is disabled (the user cannot write in the input, he can only click the button in order to view the options) like this :

```
$.widget("ui.combobox", {

_create: function () {
    var self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children(":selected"),
                    value = selected.val() ? $.trim(selected.text()) : "";
    var input = this.input = $("<input>")
                .attr("name", select.attr("name"))
                .attr('disabled', true)
                .insertAfter(select)
                .val(value)
                .autocomplete({ .......
```

Probably because the input is disabled, the combo-box doesn't hide after i lose focus by clicking on empty space, or clicking on another combo box (the input element has the blur event handler, but it doesn't fire).

Is there a way to set a blur event on a input element that is disabled or any way of hiding the combo-box when a user wants to lose focus?

Comment: Hi @Atzoya, I've used your approach and it works well in FF, but I added the click event to the input control too so that if the user clicks on the input the drop down appears. Works well in FF but IE9 the drop down jumps out and dissappears again. How did you work this bit out?

Comment: I checked it out and the same thing is happening in my application as well. I'm currently quite busy on another project, but as soon as i find some time I will try and find a solution to this issue. When and if i do, i will post it here.

Comment: Hi @Atzoya, I commented out the line that deals with a bug $(this).blur(); and this solved my problem. Well it works in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE 7,8 and 9. Not sure about IE6 though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rethink your strategy a bit. Autocomplete is not designed to work on a `disabled` input. Instead, I would use `readonly`. Replace:

```
.attr("disabled", true)
```

with:

```
.attr("readonly", true)
```

You will get the cursor in the `input`, but your original requirement is met.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/S77xa/1/

Comment: thanks, but the tab index is not working when I have multiple combobox!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
.attr("disabled", true);
```

**to:**

```
.attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq8tq/1/

I hope this helps!

Comment: This does disable the text box, but clicking anywhere outside the combobox doesn't close the combobox. Andrew's solution worked perfectly for me, thank you for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('comboboxname').combobox('disable');

$('comboboxname').combobox('enable');
```